# Replace missing values based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

I have the following problem

I need to replace NaN values in dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1001, np.NaN], [1001,'C'], [1004, 'D'],[1005, 'C'], 
                   [1005,'D'], [1010, np.NaN],[1010,np.NaN],[1010,'F']], columns=['CustomerNr','Costs'])
```

| CustomerNr | Costs |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | NaN |
| 1004 | D |
| 1005 | C |
| 1010 | NaN |
| 1010 | NaN |

I've tried:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1001, 'X'], [1010, 'Y']], columns=['CustomerNr','New Costs'])
```

Desired output:

| CustomerNr | Costs |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | X |
| 1004 | D |
| 1005 | C |
| 1010 | Y |
| 1010 | Y |

Comment: What is the logic? You just want to replace something, but with what?

Answer (score 1):

[Fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) `NA/NaN` values based on series mapping (on matched `'CustomerNr'` values):

```
df1['Costs'].fillna(df1['CustomerNr']
                    .map(df2.set_index('CustomerNr')['New Costs']), inplace=True)
```

---

```
   CustomerNr Costs
0        1001     X
1        1001     C
2        1004     D
3        1005     C
4        1005     D
5        1010     Y
6        1010     Y
7        1010     F
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1001, np.NaN], [1001,'C'], [1004, 'D'],[1005, 'C'], 
                   [1005,'D'], [1010, np.NaN],[1010,np.NaN],[1010,'F']], columns=['CustomerNr','Costs'])

replace_dict = {1001:"X",1010:"Y"}

df1['Costs'] = df1.apply(lambda x: replace_dict.get(x['CustomerNr']) if pd.isna(x['Costs']) else x['Costs'], axis=1)
```

Explanation: creates a dictionary (`replace_dict`) that maps the values to assign based on the value of `CustomerNr` column and use `apply.()` to assign those values if the value in `CustomerNr` is `nan`, else apply the original value of `Costs`